# Zener diodes multiple breakdown voltages

Tags: diodes

How could there be zener diodes with different breakdown voltages since the chemical bond of the Si atom with the B- atom has the same strength in all occasions?

Comment: Slightly different dopings, different annealing times, etc.

Comment: Slightly different dopping will change the width of the depletion region.

Comment: The chemical bond between Si and B atoms is not what's breaking down in the Zener effect.

Comment: Yes I know it is because of quantum tunneling.